# Silverlight 4 Code Signing

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have successfully signed my elevated trust xap file with a cert bought from comodo. This works great on my local machine but when I transfer my xap to our server it is as if the xap had not been signed. Am I missing something that I need to do on the server to allow this to work?

Thanks for any questions or input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a strange Firefox caching problem. The xap was signed but because i had installed the app previously unsigned through firefox it still beleived it to be unsigned.